# Javascript: Stop scrolling after a scroll fling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

On mobile devices (or most devices with touch screens) it is possible to scroll via a fling. The scrolling then goes on (but decelerates), even when the user lifted his/her finger from the screen.

Is it possible to stop that additional scrolling with Javascript (jquery)?

Comment: Do you want no scrolling at all or just for it to stop when you lift your finger?

Comment: I actually have a button to immediately scroll to the end of the page, by executing `$('html, body').scrollTop( $(document).height() );`. However, the button does not work when the page is scrolling, which is why I want to cancel that first.

Comment: have you prevented the default? Something like with `touchend` use `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: No, I haven't. The user should be able to scroll, I only would like to cancel that running scroll event at some point.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303371/touchscreen-scroll-disable

Comment: This does only prevent new touches from scrolling but does not cancel running scrolls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69510/discussion-between-lucusp-and-janoliver).

Comment: have you found a way?